# Creating a pig latin translator in ruby, having trouble with multiple words

Tags: ruby

My code works fine for one word, so the searcher Proc works fine. I was trying to get it to work for multiple words by storing them in an array and then passing each word to the proc and putting them together, but when I test something such as "eat pie" it returns this. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Failures:

1) translate translates two words
 Failure/Error: s.should == "eatay iepay"
   expected: "eatay iepay"
        got: "eat pieay eat pieayay" (using ==)
 # ./04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Heres my code:

```
def translate(x)
  array = x.split(' ')  
  searcher = Proc.new{ 
    if x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 0
      x = x + "ay"
    elsif x[0..1] == "qu"
      first = x.chr
      x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
      second = x.chr
      x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
      x = x + first + second + "ay"
   elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 1
     first = x.chr
     x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
     x = x + first + "ay"
  elsif x[1..2] == "qu"
     first = x.chr
     x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
     second = x.chr
     x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
     third = x.chr
     x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
     x = x + first + second + third +"ay"
  elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 2
    first = x.chr.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    second = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + second + "ay"
 elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 3
   first = x.chr
   x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
   second = x.chr
   x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
   third = x.chr
   x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
   x = x + first + second + third +"ay"
else
  x
end
}
if array.count == 1
  searcher.call
  return x
else
  return array.collect(&searcher).join(' ')
end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is pretty good for a first question (+1).  I haven't worked with Ruby, but what I'd do first is break apart the statement `return array.collect(&searcher).join(' ')` because it looks like you're not parsing what you want to parse.  Or maybe simplify things (perhaps making it less Ruby-like) but make it clear that you're doing what you said you wanted to do in the question statement, because that part looks reasonable.

Comment: @sawa I think the OP's question is "Why isn't this code giving the output I want?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to `x` in your Proc `searcher` which is closed over the argument `x` passed into `translate`, when what you really mean to do is process each element of the array one at a time.

I altered the structure of your code to be easier to reason about - by eliminating the anonymous `Proc` and used an idiomatic Ruby map to process the string - whether its one or more words.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def translate_word(x)
  if x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 0
    x = x + "ay"
  elsif x[0..1] == "qu"
    first = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    second = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + second + "ay"
  elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 1
    first = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + "ay"
  elsif x[1..2] == "qu"
    first = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    second = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    third = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + second + third +"ay"
  elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 2
    first = x.chr.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    second = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + second + "ay"
  elsif x.index(/[aeiou]/) == 3
    first = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    second = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    third = x.chr
    x.reverse!.chop!.reverse!
    x = x + first + second + third +"ay"
  else
    x
  end
end

words = ARGV[0].split(' ').map { |word| translate_word(word) }.join(' ')
puts words
```

Verified by `chmod +x pig_latin` then:

```
./pig_latin "eat pie"
./pig_latin "eat"
```

Comment: thank-you cfeduke, I just added the second to last line to it's own function traslate_words and got it working.